# C#: Text document goes to 4 lines. Trying to store it in an array. That would be an array of 3 right? Well I'm getting an element out of range error.

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to store data from one csv file in an array, and data from another csv file into another array. Then add the stored units in each index and output the totals to a new csv file.

Example:

```
totalsArray[0] = inventoryArray[0] + pricesArray[0]
```

Upon posting this question, its showing me similar questions so I clicked them. Those questions are people not understanding that an array index starts at 0 not 1. Well I *assume* that I've set up my arrays properly.

```
        string inventory = "C:\\Users\\herb\\Desktop\\Inventory.csv";
        string prices = "C:\\Users\\herb\\Desktop\\Prices.csv";
        string text_line = "";
        string finalFile = "C:\\Users\\herb\\Desktop\\Totaled.csv";


        var lineInventory = File.ReadAllLines(inventory);
        string[] inventoryArray = new string[3];


        var linePrices = File.ReadAllLines(prices);
        string[] pricesArray = new string[3];

        string[] totalsArray = new string[3];

        totalsArray[0] = inventoryArray[0] + pricesArray[0];
        totalsArray[1] = inventoryArray[1] + pricesArray[1];
        totalsArray[2] = inventoryArray[2] + pricesArray[2];
        totalsArray[3] = inventoryArray[3] + pricesArray[3];


        StreamWriter finalWriter;
        finalWriter = new StreamWriter(finalFile, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            text_line = text_line + totalsArray[i] + "\r\n";
            finalWriter.WriteLine(totalsArray[i]);
        }


        MessageBox.Show("All done");
```

My index should be 3 right?
The contents of inventory.csv is

```
Snickers,8
Milkyway,5
Reeses,3
Butterfinger,4
```

prices.csv is

```
Snickers,1.35
Milkyway,2.00
Reeses,1.50
Butterfinger,3.15
```

Also, I'm sure even if the array wasn't the issue, this code still wouldn't work since I'm trying to add snickers,4 instead of just 4. I was going to figure that out after I fixed the array. I'm guessing I need tryParse.

Comment: Include the stacktrace.

Comment: The index starts at 0 but your array is of size 4 since it can hold 4 things. Should be `string[] totalsArray = new string[4];`

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you want this line `totalsArray[0] = inventoryArray[0] + pricesArray[0]` to be `totalsArray[0] = inventoryArray[0] * pricesArray[0]` if you are calculating the total price of each item in inventory.

Comment: length should be 4 then only you can iterate and assign array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3]

Answer (score 2):

An array *index* does indeed start at 0, so the 4th item is myArray[3], but when you're specifying the *size* of an array you're not using the index. You're just specifying the size - how many elements it can contain. So you want to give your array a size of 4, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

you create an array with 3 elements here

```
string[] pricesArray = new string[3];
```

but trying to access index 3 here (which is the 4th element):

```
totalsArray[3] = inventoryArray[3] + pricesArray[3];
```

This looks like the problem to me, if you want an array holding 4 elements, do:

```
string[] pricesArray = new string[4];
```

then you can access the indices 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score -1):

Did you close the StreamWriter properly in the end of your code by putting finalWriter.close(); after showing message box